# How to increase importance of a column in Decision Tree?

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

I hava dataset with **name,ratings,ratings_count,genres** columns.

Ex: *Movies_Data.csv*

```
   Name             ratings ratings_count Action Adventure Horror Musical Thriller       
    Mad-Max            2           7         1        0       0       0       1
    Mitchell[1975]     3.25        2         1        0       0       0       1
    John Wick          4.23        4         1        0       0       0       0
    Insidious          3.75        10        0        0       1       0       0
```

I divided it into **features** and **labels**. Then Performed Label Encoding for the **Name** column.

Here's my features Dataset after split.

**features:**

```
ratings ratings_count Action Adventure Horror Musical Thriller       
   2           7         1        0       0       0       1
   3.25        2         1        0       0       0       1
   4.23        4         1        0       0       0       0
   3.75        10        0        0       1       0       0
```

Now the problem is I have around *18* ***'Genre'*** Columns. So i think my decision tree is giving more importance to the these columns rather than *ratings* and *ratings_count*.

Like if i ask the tree to predict a movie with the following parameters:

```
ratings:3 ratings_count:2 Action:1 Adventure:0 Horror:0 Musical:0 Thriller:1
```

It should obviously predict **Mitchell[1975]** since the *ratings:3* is near to *3.25* and *ratings_count* is same as my input. But it's predicting **Mad-Max**.
How can i increase the importance of the ratings and ratings_count column?

I'm new to ML. So is there any other way or any other algorithm can i use for better recommendations?

P.s.I know we can use neural networks but i need to stick to Basic ML algorithms only.

Thanks!

Comment: For basic trees, you can plot the tree to understand it decision process. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Random Forests almost always bring better results than Decision Trees. They have a bit more hyperparameters to tune, but that can also help you to bring better results. It's called an Ensemble algorithm and it works well because it averages lots of Decision Trees. It has less overfitting problems, so it should perform better.

If you're still having trouble, you might try to fuse some categories (or get more data), so your algorithm can correctly infer the rating's importance.

Also, this question might be better suited for Cross Validated, where you can ask more theoretical questions.

Good luck !

Comment: I don't know much about stack. What is cross validated? And btw I'll surely try implementing random forest. Thanks!

Comment: Cross Validated is a webpage for Theoretical discussion about ML/Statistics. There you can ask about which algorithm performs better, which metrics to use, why your results aren't what you expect, even though the code is right, etc. StackOverflow is more for help with code that doesn't work or an idea you are not being capable to implement in code